# what happens in android if you lose connection in mid download?

Tags: java, android, networking

I seem to be getting corrupt files, and I need to know if this is a possibility, and make sure I am handling it right.

I have an app that may download a whole lot of back to back music files.
If when downloading using the below method, a connection were suddenly lost mid connection what would happen?
Would I catch an exception? or would I return half completed (corrupt) data?
I need to make sure that I am not attempting to save incomplete data.

```
    public static InputStream getHTTPRequest(HttpGet getRequest, HttpParams params)
    {
        final String TAG = "getHTTPRequest";

        if (params != null)
        {
            getRequest.setParams(params);
        }

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        if(getRequest == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "The HttpGet param passed in was null, returning null");
            return null;
        }

        try {

            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "status not ok");
                Log.d(TAG, "status = " + Integer.toString(statusCode));
                Log.d(TAG, "url = " + getRequest.getURI().toString());
                return null;
            }

            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            return getResponseEntity.getContent();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException: getRequest.abort");
            getRequest.abort();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of exceptions which could be thrown during performing IO Operation and you should handle them gracefully here is complete list of exceptions extended by IOException http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html

you don't need to handle all of them but few of them, you can delete your file in case if corrupt file is downloaded.